# on android table flash object blink on focus

Tags: html, flash, browser, android

I have page with flash object on it. 
something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyFlash</title>
</head>
<body onLoad="onLoadFunc()">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoadFunc(){
        //
    }
    </script>
    <div>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="MyFlash" width="100%" height="100%"  
        allowScriptAccess="always" >
        <param name="movie" value="MyFlash.swf"/>
        <EMBED src="MyFlash.swf" style="WIDTH:620;HEIGHT:460" NAME="MyFlash" allowScriptAccess="always" />  
    </object >
    </div>
</body>
```

When this page shown on tablet browser (samsung galaxy tab and every browser in android market), flash object "blinks" for half seconds, when getting focus. On desktop computer (win7, every browser) it doesn't happens. 
I tried listen to events from family "onTouch", but didn't succeed prevent this blinking.  Only idea is set focus onLoad on this object, but it doesn't prevent blinking if object lose focus and get it back.
Thank you.